# Xamarin broadcast receiver doesn't receive

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-broadcast

I have a BroadcastReceiver that isn't receiving any broadcasts.

```
[BroadcastReceiver]
[IntentFilter(new[] { _broadcastId })]
public class CallBroadcaster : BroadcastReceiver, IAcceptCallService
{
   const string _broadcastId = "headExtension.droid.services.AcceptIndividualCall";

   public CallBroadcaster ()
   { 
   }

   Activity CurrentActivity
   {
      get { return Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAndroidCurrentTopActivity>().Activity; }
   }

   public void Send()
   {
      var intent = new Intent(_broadcastId);
      intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraText, "Accept");
      intent.SetType("text/plain");

      CurrentActivity.SendBroadcast(intent);
   }

   public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Received");
   }
}
```

The OnReceive method is never hit. How do I correctly implement a broadcast receiver in xamarin.

There is only one project here so this is not a duplicate of the question about receiving an intent from another project.

Comment: Please include the code that is triggering the broadcast.

Comment: @matthewrdev see the send function in the already included code

Comment: @SushiHangover That other question is about doing it from a different project I only have one project. And also the answers don't help.

Comment: @trampster Does not really matter if it is being called from the same project or not, assign the `Name` element of your `BroadcastReceiver` attribute.

Comment: @SushiHangover The solution was to use DataMimeType="text/plain" in the intent filter, that other question would never have told me that, so directing people there would not have helped.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working:
The problem was with the datatype. The intent was sent with "text/plain" and the IntentFilter for receiving didn't match.

The solution is to add DataMimeType="text/plain" to the intent filter as follows:

```
[BroadcastReceiver]
[IntentFilter(new[] { _broadcastId }, DataMimeType="text/plain")]
public class CallBroadcaster : BroadcastReceiver, IAcceptCallService
{
   const string _broadcastId =     "headExtension.droid.services.AcceptIndividualCall";

   public CallBroadcaster ()
   { 
   }

   Activity CurrentActivity
   {
      get { return Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAndroidCurrentTopActivity>().Activity; }
   }

   public void Send()
   {
      var intent = new Intent(_broadcastId);
      intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraText, "Accept");
      intent.SetType("text/plain");

      CurrentActivity.SendBroadcast(intent);
   }

   public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Received");
   }
}
```